# What are the different platforms in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, platform

What are these - **force.com**, **data.com**, **site.com**, **work.com** and don't know what else are there in Salesforce? What are the key differences among themselves?

Answer (score 0):

**force.com** - is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) product designed to simplify the development and deployment of cloud-based applications and websites. Developers can create apps and websites through the cloud IDE (integrated development environment) and deploy them quickly to Force.com’s multi-tenant servers. 
Force.com is owned by Software as a Service (SaaS) vendor Salesforce.com, who calls the product a social and mobile app development platform. See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzE6haADxRc)

**data.com** - is the sales and lead generation component of force.com's Sales Cloud platform. The Data.com platform enables sharing of contact data (similar to what is found on business cards) among members through its large user-generated database. Users not only access the database but also through their interactions constantly build, maintain and update its records, which include tens of millions of contacts from over four million companies. Data.com [keynotes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fkc80WftXFE)

**site.com** - is a Community Builder, a Web content management system (CMS) that makes it easy to build dynamic, data-driven Web pages quickly, edit content in real time, and manage your websites. From the Site.com tab in the Site.com app, you can launch Site.com Studio, which provides a separate, dedicated environment for creating and editing pixel-perfect, custom websites. Site administrators and designers can create and style Web pages, and add features such as navigation menus, images, and text areas using drag-and-drop page elements, while ensuring the site's pages match the look and feel of the company's brand. And content contributors, such as marketing users, can browse and update website content directly in a simplified Site.com Studio environment. Additionally, websites built with Site.com benefit from running on Salesforce’s trusted global infrastructure. site.com is a part of force.com PaaS

**work.com** - is a corporate performance management platform for sales representatives with a user interface (UI) that resembles a social networking website. The platform, which is a Salesforce product, targets employee engagement in three areas: alignment of team and personal goals with business goals, motivation through public recognition and real-time performance feedback. Employees are encouraged to meet goals through a system that emphasizes recognition and rewards. See [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=97&v=1jEK_fK3eIo)

there are a lot of different salesfroce products. TO check full list of them visit [this](https://www.salesforce.com/eu/products/?d=70130000000NRbl) page